# I have a very basic world koajs web app that i need to test on azure

Tags: node.js, azure, azure-web-app-service, koa

I need to test koajs support on azure. since koajs uses --harmony flag with node to take advantage of generators its very hard to tweek node on azure.

following is the code for server.js file.

```
var koa = require("koa")
var app = koa();

app.use(function * () {
    this.body = "Hello World!";
});

app.listen(80);
console.log("The app is listening. Port 80");
```

I have a web app on azure that use git local publising to push code online. how can i configure node to use --harmony switch?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can control the node command line by using the **nodeProcessCommandLine** configuration setting which can be specified in an **iisnode.yml** config file as detailed in the "advanced scenarios" section of [this post](http://tomasz.janczuk.org/2012/09/selecting-nodejs-version-in-windows.html). This allows you to pass additional command line switches, choose your node version, point to your own deployed node build, etc.

For example:

```
nodeProcessCommandLine: "D:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs\0.10.18\node.exe" --harmony
```

Your specific issue is discussed in more detail in [this github issue](https://github.com/tjanczuk/iisnode/issues/315).

Comment: I am accepting your answer with an edit. Azure now support new versions of node and npm and these new versions doesn't require --harmony flag.